# Module not found in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYWbb.png)

```
import React from "react"

var mysql=require('sql');

var con=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"root"
}
);
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected");
});
```

I tried to run a code for database connectivity for mysql in node.js but this happens

Answer (score 0):

You need to write node (name of folder that have your http listiner)

Comment: Its already installed

Comment: I have updated my answer depending on the img